# Restrict Data consumtion by playStore Over WIFI

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, google-play-services

My Google Play Store application has gone haywire.It is downloading heavily without even notifying anything about what it is downloading and the rate has gone up by 2.5 times in past 2 days.I tried everything to stop it.I selected do-not auto update apps in play store settings and turned off all kinds of Sync.But it still isn't working.
Is there any way i can restrict data consumed by my google play store on WiFi?
I have a rooted device.

Comment: How's the speed of your Wi-Fi? Are the Google Play Services and Play Store running latest update? // You can consider [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall) in combination with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) so that Play Store would  connect to Wi-Fi if only it is in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

you can start clearing data cache for play store app in .. settings>apps>all apps>play store>clear data.

It would probably solve your issue if it still lingers than remove your google account from settings>accounts>google account>remove this account.

Add again the same account with your credentials.. it would solve the issue.